# How can I get default data from route in mojolicious?

Tags: perl, routes, mojolicious

I want to create some routes with restrictions by role. Something like this:

```
my $auth = $app->routes->under->to('auth#check');
$auth->get('/list')->to('some#list')->name('list');
$auth->get('/add')->to('some#add', roles => ['user', 'admin'])->name('add');
```

I don't have any problem with checking `roles` in `after_dispatch` hook. But I cannot access this data when I'm trying to create a links for this routes.

For example, I'm a `guest` on `/list` route and want to form menu with available links. So, I have to check `roles` from route `/add` to decide to show this link or not.

For this moment I found only one way to get default data from route with name:

```
 app->routes->lookup('add')->pattern->defaults->{roles}
```

And it looks like a hack. How I can do this in a right way?

Comment: Are you sure you required the default and not current one?

Answer (score 0):

You are right. This method to get defaults of the route is documented [here](http://mojolicious.org/perldoc/Mojolicious/Routes/Pattern#defaults)

```
my $defaults = $pattern->defaults;
$pattern     = $pattern->defaults({foo => 'bar'});
```